# Finding the highest number of digits in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to solve this problem.(Code the program that finds the highest number of digits of the elements of an array.)

```
int main() 

{
    
    int array[15]={5,-2,2,-4,64,51,-7,8,9,-20,11,52,-155,14,-15};
    int i;
    
    for(i=0;i<15;i++)
    {
                
        if(array[i]>array[j])
        {
            printf("%d ",array[i]); 
        }
    }

    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Step one is to write a function that finds the number of digits in a single number

Comment: What is your thought pattern here? What is `j`?